# I can't play some Youtube videos

Tags: 16.04, video, youtube

I don't know whether this question already asked or not in Askubuntu. So, what my question is now I am facing a (weired) problem while playing Youtube videos. Some of the videos streaming well but some videos are not. I am getting an error message saying that **"An error occurred. Please try again later(Playback ID: some playback id)**. I tried both in Mozilla as well as Chrome but no luck. Flash plug-in installed correctly that's why some videos playing well. I restarted my PC and router still same problem.

I tried the following command also
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64

So, can anyone help me please.

Comment: this might be useful: [My youtube videos won't load. "an error occured, please try again later"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1039936)

Answer (score 2):

Close all browsers and do the following:

1. After having installed ubuntu-restricted-extras, uninstall flashplugin-installer with the following command:
   `sudo apt-get remove --purge flashplugin-installer`
2. `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin` (which is 64bit and more stable than flashplugin-installer (32bit))
3. Open Firefox > Click Help in Menu bar at the top > Troubleshooting Information > Refresh Firefox, after which it will start up cleanly.
4. Make sure AdBlock Plus is disabled on the YouTube website (if you have that addon installed).

Try YouTube now and see if it worked.

Comment: Your answer not solved my problem but `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin` solution solved my Adobe Flash Player problem. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried playing those videos on YouTube on another PC?  If yes, and they still dont play, i think you should consider changing your DNS's in your network settings to google's DNS's. Such as 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, try it and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, my experience with the given error message has to do with a *bad internet connection.*

If this is the problem,

- You could change the quality of the streaming. (144p, 240p, 360p, etc.)
- You could get closer to the router.
- You could kick people off of the network your using.
- Or you could give up on watching YouTube. (Probably not the best solution...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 10Mbps Internet connection so _bad Internet connection_  not actual problem. As mentioned in my question some of the Youtube videos not playing. Your posts third point is funny ;).

Answer (score 1):

Having video-related probs, (like html5 not supported...etc including youtube), This does magic!!

```
apt-get install libavcodec-extra
```

it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i'm not sure. 3mpbs download is still really good and since this is about 0.3fps youtube stuff on ubuntu i think an Android emulator would work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could detail the steps to using an Android emulator to solve this issue.

Comment: Anbox is the case but warning, it dosent work on budgie.