# Ubuntu 16.04, Only youtube does not work

Tags: firefox, youtube

I just started using Ubuntu 16.04 today, I was on Windows 7, and I decided to change for Linux. I noticed that when I launch Firefox, every websites work except Youtube, when I am on the website, the window becomes gray, Firefox stops working and the operating system is blocked, I need to shut it down with the power button because I cannot click on anything on the screen even though, my mouse can move. So I would like to know if there is a solution.
Thank you

Comment: If your computer has a discrete graphics card, the graphics card may need to be replaced.

Comment: Maybe related: [I can't play some Youtube videos](https://askubuntu.com/q/806155/504066).

Comment: When you say website page goes grey, does this occur when you visit the site generally, or only if you try to play a video on there? If you press keys Ctrl+Alt+t, does the terminal window come up?

Comment: It goes automatically gray, when I visit the website, sometimes the operating system is crashing but sometimes only the windows is not responding and closing it is enough, all the other websites work, even the similar one as Rutube just Youtube does not work. Since then, my operating system did not crash so I cannot try to prress the keys but I will try next time, thank you.

Comment: try to use youtube without hardware acceleration in browser check *Options* - *General* and remove the tick.